# Compare Joda LocalDateTime and DateTime within range

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to write a method that will take a `LocalDateTime` and a `DateTime` (using **Joda 1.3**) and determine if they are within 30 minutes of one another. Here's the best I can come up with, but I *know* there has to be a better/cleaner/more efficient way:

```
public boolean isWithin30MinsOfEachOther(LocalDateTime localDateTime, DateTime dateTime) {
    return (
        localDateTime.getYear() == dateTime.getYear() &&
        localDateTime.getMonthOfYear() == dateTime.getMonthOfYear() &&
        localDateTime.getDayOfMonth() == dateTime.getDayOfMonth() &&
        localDateTime.getHourOfDay() == dateTime.getHourOfDay() &&
        Math.abs((localDateTime.getMinuteOfHour() - dateTime.getMinuteOfHour())) <= 30
    );
)
```

Not to mention I don't think this works if, say, `localDateTime` is December 31, 2012 23:58:00 and `dateTime` is January 1, 2013 00:01:00. Same thing with the beginning/end of two different months and days. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class?

As an example:

```
  Duration myDuration=new Duration(localDateTime.toDateTime(), dateTime);
  return Math.abs(myDuration.getMillis())<=30*60*1000;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas Narros, however this is Joda 1.3 and `getStandardMinutes` is not available in the API. Also, I cannot simply update to a more modern version, I am stuck with 1.3.

Comment: What if I used `getMillis()` instead and then just divided by 1,000?

Comment: @HeineyBehinds true, fixing it. Check my edition please (division by 60 and by 1000, or clearer, converting 30 to millis multiplying for 60 and 1000)...

Comment: Thanks again @Tomas Narros - (+1) - just curious what's the significance of 30 and 60?

Comment: @HeineyBehinds 30 minutes, as your question requested :), 60 seconds per minute, and 1000 miliseconds per second.

Comment: Ahh, I got so caught up in the API docs I lost sight of the original question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
return Math.abs(localDateTime.getLocalMillis() 
                - dateTime.toLocalDateTime().getLocalMillis()) < 30 * 60 * 1000;
```